# How To Delete GitHub Repository With No Settings Icon

Tags: github, repository

How do I delete a repository from GitHub when there is no **Settings** icon?

[image]

Everything I've found refers to the **Settings** icon and then scrolling to the bottom to type in the Repository name for confirmation, but what do I do when there is no **Settings** icon?

Comment: Are you an admin for this repository, or have you been added as a collaborator with Admin privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no Settings icon, then you are not an administrator of the repository.  As such, you cannot delete the repository or change any of its settings.

If you think the repository should be deleted, you can ask an administrator of the repository or the organization to delete it.  If you own the repository, check that you're signed in and using the correct account.